# How to get this parent child query data in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am building a simple messaging system and I have a messageSchema which is setup as below:

```
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
replyTo: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Message',
    default: null,
},
name: {
    type: Object,
    required: [true, 'Message has a name'],
},
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
},
email: {
    type: Object,
    required: [true, 'Message has a email'],
},
subject: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Message has a subject'],
},
content: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Message has content'],
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
},
status: {
    type: String,
    default: 'unread',
    required: [true, 'Message has a status'],
},});
```

Sample data below:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a'),
        name: 'Person 1',
        createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T01:00:00.000Z'),
        subject: 'M1',
        content: 'M1 content',
        replyTo: null,
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281b'),
        name: 'Person 2',
        subject: 'M2 - Reply 1 to M1',
        content: 'M2 content',
        createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T02:00:00.000Z'),
        replyTo: ObjectId('53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a'),
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281c'),
        name: 'Person 3',
        subject: 'M3 - Reply 2 to M1',
        content: 'M3 content',
        createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T03:00:00.000Z'),
        replyTo: ObjectId('53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a'),
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281d'),
        name: 'Person 4',
        subject: 'M4',
        content: 'M4 content',
        createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T02:30:00.000Z'),
        replyTo: null,
    },
];
```

I am now trying to query the sample above to produce an inbox style response, so that the root message (no replyTo) is the top-level message, has a latest node with latest message info, and has children(if any) in a children node. See below for desired output.

```
[
{
    _id: ObjectId('53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a'),
    name: 'Person 1',
    createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T01:00:00.000Z'),
    subject: 'M1',
    content: 'M1 content',
    replyTo: null,
    latest: {
        _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281c'),
        name: 'Person 3',
        subject: 'M3 - Reply 2 to M1',
        content: 'M3 content',
        createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T03:00:00.000Z'),
        replyTo: ObjectId('53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a'),
    },
    children: [
            {
                _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281b'),
                name: 'Person 2',
                subject: 'M2 - Reply 1 to M1',
                content: 'M2 content',
                createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T02:00:00.000Z'),
                replyTo: ObjectId('53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a'),
            },
            {
                _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281c'),
                name: 'Person 3',
                subject: 'M3 - Reply 2 to M1',
                content: 'M3 content',
                createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T03:00:00.000Z'),
                replyTo: ObjectId('53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a'),
            },
        ]
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281d'),
    name: 'Person 4',
    subject: 'M4',
    content: 'M4 content',
    createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T02:30:00.000Z'),
    replyTo: null,
    latest: {
        _id: ObjectId('53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281d'),
        name: 'Person 4',
        subject: 'M4',
        content: 'M4 content',
        createdAt: ISODate('2021-01-01T02:30:00.000Z'),
        replyTo: null,
    },
    children: []
},];
```

Appreciate any help in getting this query sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation pipeline stages,

- `$match` `replyTo` us null condition
- [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) to join same collection to get reply messages in `children`
- `$addFields` to check condition is `children` is empty then return root document otherwise return last element from children

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { replyTo: null } },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "replyTo",
      "as": "children"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      latest: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [{ $size: "$children" }, 0] },
          "$$ROOT",
          { $arrayElemAt: [{$slice: ["$children", -1]}, 0] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9HCYqnOKw-e)

> For query optimization you can do last stage $addFields process in your client side.

Comment: Looks perfect ! Just had to add 

 {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1,
      parent: -1,
      createdAt: 1,  
    },
  },

to get the right sorting. 

What do you mean by "For query optimization you can do last stage $addFields process in your client side."?

Comment: I'm getting ""Unrecognized expression '$last'" when I run it under node/mongoose. Any ideas?

Comment: $last is supported from mongodb 4.4 so might be your mongodb version is older than 4.4, i have updated with solution in older version, query optimization means, how to perform query faster, and quick response, so you can reduce last stage operation $addFields processing, i think you can do it easily in your client code side. for query optimization refer [aggregation-pipeline-optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/)

Comment: Hello! I need to do exactly what you do @turivishal but I'm not accessing the collection directly, I'm accessing the collection reference. How can I do it? I don't find examples

Comment: @Izlia can you show your question link, so i can review it.